# Finding the closure of a set using only topological definitions

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set $X = \{(-1)^n - \frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}, n > 0\}$.

I'm trying to find the closure of the set.

I know intuitively using real analysis that the closure includes $X$ and the limit points 1 and -1. So the closure must include these as well.

But how do I show that the elements of $X$ and 1 and -1 are the only elements of the closure using topological notions of closure. i.e. the intersection of all closed sets containing $X$. Couldn't there possibly be more elements in the closure of $X$?

I also have the result that $x \in \overline{X}$ iff every open set $A$ containing $x$ is such that $A \cap X \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Show that this set is closed.

Comment: What you want to prove is basically the equivalence of two definitions of closure of a set. You don't need an example set for that, the proof holds for all sets in general, and is quite simple for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Take $y\notin X\cup\{1,-1\}$. Since $y$ is not a accumulation point of the sequence, there is some $r>0$ such that $(y-r,y+r)$ contains only finitely many elements of the sequence. If $F$ is that finite set, let $\delta=\min\{|y-t|\mid t\in F\}$. Since $y$ does not belong to the sequence, then it does not belong to $F$, and therefore $\delta>0$. So, $\left(y-\min\{r,\delta\},y+\min\{r,\delta\}\right)$ has no element of $X\cup\{1,-1\}$. This proves that $y\notin\overline{X\cup\{1,-1\}}$.

Comment: How do you know that $(y-r,y+r)$ only contains finitely many elements of the sequence?

Comment: I explained that in my answer: because $y$ is not an accumulation point of the sequence.